# html table column width size exact as column content

Tags: html, css

I want to build a table with a column, which has exactly the size of the content.

I have the following code:

```css
table {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #2c3d4b;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
td, th {
  padding: 25px 25px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
thead {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px black;
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.halfSize {
  width: 60%;
}

.autoSize {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="halfSize">Column 1</th>
      <th class="autoSize">Column 2</th>
      <th class="autoSize">Ding</th>
      <th class="autoSize">Column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
      <td>R1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jen8xkrm/36/

When change the size of the screen, the column width of column "Ding" becomes larger.
But I want it exactly fitting the text.
If anything needs to grow, it would be okay if all other columns not with class "autoSize" grows.

Comment: You would have to use `table-layout:fixed`, and explicitly _specify_ a width for the "ding" column.

Comment: If I explicit set a width for "ding", how is it possible to have a dynamic size matching the largest row of the column "ding" ?

Comment: use a grid layout instead of a table

Comment: as your fiddle stands, you can use width on the third td : `td:nth-child(3) {width:0}`  . If your table may have spanning columns, you may also use colgroup to set that width on a specific column `col:nth-child(3) {width:0}`  example https://jsfiddle.net/h31sbxfa/ width:0 will let the col grow to the size of the content if the table-layout is set to its default value `table-layout:auto;`